# Download asset from Sitecore Content Hub programmatically

Tags: content-hub

I have a request from my customer to download asset from Sitecore Content Hub programatically. I googled a lot, found examples of uploading programmatically, but no downloading.

I was thinking there must be API or SDK ready to use for downloading asset from Sitecore Content Hub via code, but no info.

Is it even possible?
I found creating a public link via code and calling that endpoint as an alternative, but in my understanding, the public link is open even for anonymous users, and I do not want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your external script user has access to the original rendition of the asset, then you can download a rendition using the WebClientSDK and the `IRendition` and `IRenditionItem` objects. `IRenditionItem` has `DownloadAsync` method:

Example code:

```
var asset = await client.Entities.GetAsync(8626);
var original = asset.GetRendition("downloadOriginal");
var rendition = original.Items.FirstOrDefault();

if (rendition != null)
{
    var filename = asset.GetPropertyValue<string>(Constants.Asset.FileName);
    var directory = @"C:\Users\Stylelabs\Desktop";
    var filepath = Path.Combine(directory, filename);
    await rendition.DownloadAsync(filepath);
}
```

For more documentation, the WebClient API docs are here: https://docs.stylelabs.com/content/3.4.x/integrations/web-sdk/index.html

Rendition download example here: https://docs.stylelabs.com/content/3.4.x/integrations/sdk-common-documentation/entity/renditions.html